# W: GPG error: message in my terminal

Tags: 14.04

I get this msg in my terminal

W: GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366

How do i get rid of it?  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to download the intel drivers from their website, but have not followed the full set of [instructions](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.6-linux).

You need to open a terminal and enter

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -

wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
```